# Loading image src using a variable containing base64 data in AngularJS

Tags: image, angularjs, base64, loading, data-url

### Loading image using variable containing `base64` data in AngularJS

I am trying to find the right way to load a image source from a variable containing `base64` encoded image data (for example pulled from a canvas using `toDataURL();` ).

At first I just tried it like this:

```
<img src="{{image.dataURL}}" />
```

where the image is a scope variable with a variable `dataURL` containing the `base64` data. This is actually working pretty well, the only problem is that I get a `404` error in my console. Something like this:

> GET http://www.example.com/%7B%7Bimage.dataURL%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Not so pretty. When I tried a more angular style solution like this:

```
<img data-ng-src="image.dataURL" />
```

the images are not loading at all.
I made a fiddle which you can find <kbd>[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/4LJDB/3/)</kbd>

Any suggestions how to get rid of this error in my console?

---

### EDIT:

Gruff Bunny was right. This `<img data-ng-src="{{image.dataURL}}" />` is working...

Working solution can be found <kbd>[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/4LJDB/5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The content of the ng-src needs to be interpolated: Try this:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{image.dataURL}}"/>
```

Comment: Note that the image has to be in the full Data URI scheme: `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..."`. If you're using [angular-base64-upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/issues/21) like me, you might have to manually format it this way.

Comment: @kermit666 The ":" token is giving me troubles. How did you solved it?

Comment: I've been having this problem all day. Still can't seem to get it no matter how I format it. This is in Ionic though. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I admit I spent way too much time trying to fix similar problem,

my problem was I had extra brace here (see three braces at end):

```
 ng-attr-src="{{aad.form.imageBase64Temp}}}"
```