# browser automatically adding relative path to base64 image data

Tags: angularjs, html, image, base64

i am trying to show thumbnails in base64 encoded form .This is how it looks ( angularjs + php ) :

```
 <a ng-href="{{field.value.value_readonly}}">
          <img src="{{field.value.thumb}}" />
  </a>
```

however, when rendered on browser , it looks like this:

```
<a ng-href="/faisl30/http://localhost/faisl30//index.php?option=com_faicm&amp;task=getPilotEventFile&amp;idsub=14774&amp;userid=582&amp;filename=14774/582/bubbles.jpg" href="/faisl30/http://localhost/faisl30//index.php?option=com_faicm&amp;task=getPilotEventFile&amp;idsub=14774&amp;userid=582&amp;filename=14774/582/bubbles.jpg">
                            <img src="/faisl30/data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4QD4RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgEaAAUAAAABAAAAVgEbAAUAAAABAAAAXgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAE7AAIAAAAVAAAAZgITAAMAAAABAAEAAIKYAAIAAABzAAAAf...."
                                 />
                        </a>
```

as you can see it keeps inserting the "/faisl30/" ( relative path ) to both href and image src even though i am providing absolute path.

Any idea why it is happening and how to stop it ?

Comment: i have also tried ng-src and ng-data-src , in both cases "/faisl30/" got added autometically !

Comment: what php framework you using?

Comment: joomla. its not a problem in php as i verified correct response is returned.

Comment: I see. try this one then - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018776/loading-image-src-using-a-variable-containing-base64-data-in-angularjs

Comment: i have already tried  image-data-src="{{field.value.thumb}}" , but even then it comes up with a "/faisl30/" prefixed to it !

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious; have you tried dumping the raw content of `field.value.thumb` onto the page? I can't see why the relative path would be getting pushed on there, it feels more like the problem is that the relative path is already present at the time the value is bound.

Comment: Plz it would be good if u can also post the controller