# Show base64 image with data-ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make image preview after file select in AngularJS

Its HTML I'm using for selecting file and displaying it with ng repeat

```
 <input type="file" file-input="files" multiple />
 <li ng-repeat="file in files">[[file.name]] <img data-ng-src="[[todata(file)]]"></li>
```

and its my angular code

```
app.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function($parse){
               return {
                   restrict:'A',
                   link:function(scope,elm,attrs){
                       elm.bind('change', function(){


                           $parse(attrs.fileInput)
                           .assign(scope,elm[0].files)
                           scope.$apply()

                       })
                   }
               }

           }])
.controller('fileUploader', ['$scope', '$http', 
                      function ($scope, $http) {

                          $scope.todata = function(file) {
                             var oFReader = new FileReader();
                           oFReader.readAsDataURL(file);

                           oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
                               return oFREvent.target.result
                           }; 
                          }
                }]);
```

Its displaying image name but not image itself, todata function in console logging base64 converted image but in HTML its displaying nothing ..

How to display image for preview?

**Edit**

`console.log(oFREvent.target.result);` works fine but its the only one that working

Answer (score 1):

You data-ng-src should be prefixed with `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..."`
You can find a better description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018776/loading-image-src-using-a-variable-containing-base64-data-in-angularjs)

Comment: in console log strating with `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/` think its not needed

Comment: can you create a plunker for this and also copy in your base64 string of the image?