# Error loading base64 images with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, base64

In my Angular app, I'm loading some images which I download from server as base64.
I can see the images in the app without problem, but I have this errors in the console:

[image: console errors]
This is my code:

```
<img src="{{user.avatar}}">
```

And this is the output:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkwy0AgiVGdIQtN6rzCewfv0KPPggzRPSVGDZfCx9K ... a4rJcMX07V9C//Z">
```

Can anybody understand this?

Comment: your image path is incorrect!

Comment: Could you tell me why? The app shows the images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow following stackoverflow answer :
[Loading image src using a variable containing base64 data in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018776/loading-image-src-using-a-variable-containing-base64-data-in-angularjs)

I think you will find solution by reffering above link.

you need to use "src" as following:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{image.dataURL}}"/>
```